# When my app returns from gallery, it has the navbar's standard colors

Tags: ios, iphone, statusbar

my app has a custom dark navigation bar, and on the method `Application`
i put the code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

but when i came back from an image picker from gallery iOS reuse black color and use it in all the application.
Why?

Comment: Write this line in viewWillAppear from where image picker is presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi using this method you can manage the navigation bar

```
 - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
    {

        [viewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"Videos"];
        [viewController.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        if ([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: and where i implement this method?

Comment: You can imlement it in a viewController where the navigation bar issue you are facing. Thanks

Comment: `UIImagePickerController` makes strange things - in my case it breaks status bar style so we need to restore it after image picker

Comment: Hi using this [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO]; you can setStatusBarStyle property which one you needed.